# Match nested capture groups with quantifiers using QRegularExpression

Tags: c++, regex, qt, regex-group, qregularexpression

I'm trying to get with a QRegularExpression all attributes of an xml tag in the different captured groups. I use a regex matching the tags and I manage to get the capture groups containing the attribute value but with a quantifier, I get only the last one.

I use this regex :

```
<[a-z]+(?: [a-z]+=("[^"]*"))*>
```

And I would like to get "a" and "b" with this text :

```
<p a="a" b="b">
```

Here is the code:

```cpp
const QString text { "<p a=\"a\" b=\"b\">" };
const QRegularExpression pattern { "<[a-z]+(?: [a-z]+=(\"[^\"]*\"))*>" };

QRegularExpressionMatchIterator it = pattern.globalMatch(text);
while (it.hasNext())
{
    const QRegularExpressionMatch match = it.next();

    qDebug() << "Match with" << match.lastCapturedIndex() + 1 << "captured groups";
    for (int i { 0 }; i <= match.lastCapturedIndex(); ++i)
        qDebug() << match.captured(i);
}
```

And the output :

```
Match with 2 captured groups
"<p a=\"a\" b=\"b\">"
"\"b\""
```

Is it possible to get multiple capture groups with the quantifier `*` or have I to iterate using `QRegularExpressionMatchIterator` with a specific regex on the string literals?

Comment: Why regex? See [a non-regex approach here](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/31522-Qt-way-of-getting-parsing-style-attributes-from-html-tags-local-file-batch). An [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32082181/how-to-get-xml-attributes-with-this-syntax-using-qt-dom) here. A more generic: [How to parse an HTML file with QT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49223317/how-to-parse-an-html-file-with-qt)

Comment: It's because I use this in a QSyntaxHighlighter ^^

Answer (score 2):

[This expression](https://regex101.com/r/o3T8cu/1) might help you to simply capture those attributes and it is not bounded from left and right:

```
([A-z]+)(=\x22)([A-z]+)(\x22)
```

[image]

#### Graph

This graph shows how the expression would work and you can visualize other expressions in this [link](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24), if you wish to know:

[image]

---

If you would like to add additional boundaries to it, which you might want to do so, you can further extend it, maybe to something [similar to](https://regex101.com/r/UwjdDq/1/):

```
(?:^<p )?([A-z]+)(=\x22)([A-z]+)(\x22)
```

#### Test for RegEx

```js
const regex = /(?:^<p )?([A-z]+)(=\x22)([A-z]+)(\x22)/gm;
const str = `<p attributeA="foo" attributeB="bar" attributeC="baz" attributeD="qux"></p>`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But here I still have to loop using the regex engine (QRegularExpressionMatchIterator) and we can't have all the attributes in the different capture groups of one match. Is that correct ?